# Overflow:hidden not respecting border-radius property in webkit only ( works in IE and FF )

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I've seen a few issues like this around, but mine seems to need a more complex fix since it's related to an animation.

The HTML:

```
<li class="picFrame frame6">
    <img src="img/FRAME6.png" class="frameObj frame6">
    <a href="img/image.jpg" id="ilightbox" class="picFrameMainLink">
        <span>Single Image</span>
        <div class="picSliderWrapper">
             <div class="picSlider">
                <div class="picSliderContent">
                    some text
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </a>
</li>
```

The basic idea is that the anchor tag has a border-radius of 119px all around. However, the picSlider div uses an image as its background. That image is larger than the containing anchor, but the border-radius and overflow:hidden styles don't seem to hide the overflow.

This only occurs in webkit browsers, and it often only occurs when the hover animation plays. The animation just uses jQuery to change the 'top' style of the div:

```
whateverDiv.animate({ top: topVal }
```

I've set up an example of this [here](http://dominic-c.com/StoryClub/realSite.html). Hover over the center to see the issue in action.

I've tried a few of the other solutions out there, but many of them seem to rely on it being a static image. Chrome seems to redraw the elements correctly if I change some css in the inspector on the fly, but then reverts to showing the overflow once the animation begins.

Any help at all with this would be great!

EDIT:

I'm still struggling with this. Here's a screenshot of how this looks in both the broken and working states.

[image]

Any help with this at all would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing no difference between the appearance in chrome from firefox did you fix the issue?

Comment: Oh wow, I just updated Chrome and the issue has disappeared! I was on some version of 28 and am now using Version 29.0.1547.57 m. I guess they changed something. :)

Comment: However, I am still seeing the issue in Safari version 5.1.7 (7534.57.2). I'm guessing this is a webkit issue and Apple has yet to fix their end of it.

Comment: If there's any more information I can give, please let me know. Still trying to figure this one out for Safari and <29 versions of Chrome.

I do still see this in chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m